# How to autocopy text to clipboard on clicking a button without using flash in Safari Browser

Tags: safari, copy, clipboard, safari-extension, clipboarddata

I have a button in HTML page (SAFARI BROWSER), and I need to copy the text in a `textbox` to the clipboard on clicking that button without using flash.

In my scenario I should not select the text and give copy. Just by clicking the button `autocopy` should occur. Is that possible? If yes, how?

I used `window.clipboardData`, but it is returning undefined.

`document.execCommand('copy')` also wont work.

I have to copy without manually hitting ctrl+c or command+c.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah..But they dont have any working solution. I need a solution.